# Angular ng-grid and JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular and im trying to display my JSON in ui-grid table.
Anyways, since this is similar to ng-grid I hope someone can help me.

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    Users: [
        username:'blabla',
        email:'bla@gmail.com',
        type:'admin',
        userId: [
            id:'1222'
        ]
    ],
    Teams: [
        teamName: 'team1',
        teamId: '123'
    ]
}
```

What I want is:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
data: myDataSource, 
columnDefs: [{ field: 'Users.userName', displayName: 'userName', width: 90 }]
```

But im unable to access all the objects. I can access username only if I set my data to myDataSource.Users

Comment: What do you mean you are not able to access all the objects? Can you give an example? Which object or field you are not able to access? Be specific.

Comment: your json isn't valid

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example :  http://jsfiddle.net/8jgpLn9h/

Controller :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    Users : [{
            username : 'titi',
            email : 'bla@gmail.com',
            type : 'admin',
            userId : {
                id : '1222'
            }
        },{
            username : 'toto',
            email : 'toto@gmail.com',
            type : 'admin',
            userId : {
                id : '1'
            }
        }
    ],
    Teams : {
        teamName : 'team1',
        teamId : '123'
    }
 };
 $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'data.Users' };

}]);
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but if users is an array its not possible to work with?

Comment: Im not asking how to access an object inside a JSON. im having a problem accessing it inside ng-grid field